# MySqli: is it possible to create a database?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've been sifting through the MySQLi docs, and as far as I can tell, I there's no way to create a database using PHP and MySQLi. Is this correct?

Comment: what about mysqli_query....

Comment: `$db->query("CREATE DATABASE x");`. This isnt even a real question.

Comment: MySQLi is a set of PHP functions. Use a query written in mysql language to create your database...

Comment: Thank you. I was under the impression that mysqli::query is to do queries AFTER a DB connection was established (as opposed to a server connection, where the connection is made minus DB name.

Comment: I will have to also note here that several people downgraded my question, when in fact I did go through the entire MySQLi PHP manual, and there isn't a single create DB example, leading me to believe that the mysqli::query is only used after a DB is selected. Part of the issue is that I had incorrect MySQL credentials, so my attempts to create the DB were unsuccessful.

Comment: Your question shows no research into what MySQLi is: an *abstraction layer*. If you know SQL syntax and looked into that, you would know the universal SQL database creation command is `CREATE (DATABASE|SCHEMA) name`. Furthermore, how are you supposed to create a database inside the encrypted dataset that mysql uses without first connecting to it? This isn't MongoDB; you're not creating a collection lazily as you call it.

Comment: The ONLY thing that's not an abstraction layer, is assembler code. So unless you can point to an example in the MySQLi manual, I don't see the point of your comment. PS: making assumptions about what I know or do not know is not really pertinent to the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The CREATE DATABASE statement is used to create a database in MySQL.

> - Syntax:

```
CREATE DATABASE database_name
```

To get PHP to execute the SQL instructions, first you must create a mysqli object with the
connection to the server, then use the query() method of the MySQLi class.

> - Syntax:

```
mysqliObj->query($sql_query)
```

> - mysqliObj - is the mysqli object created with new mysqli()
> - $sql_query - is a string with SQL instructions. This method sends a query or command to a MySQL connection, will return a result object, or TRUE on success. FALSE on failure.

The following example creates a database called "tests":

```
<?php
// connect to the MySQL server
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'pass');

// check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  exit('Connect failed: '. mysqli_connect_error());
}

// sql query with CREATE DATABASE
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE `tests` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci";

// Performs the $sql query on the server to create the database
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo 'Database "tests" successfully created';
}
else {
 echo 'Error: '. $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Check this link http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/php-mysql-using-mysqli

Comment: i am getting error Error creating database: Access denied for user '...'@'localhost' to database '...' on real server  while it works on wamp server.  any suggestion??

Answer (score 1):

If you have the permissions, you can execute a `CREATE DATABASE` statement using `mysqli_query`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a database.  Here is an example

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Create database
$sql="CREATE DATABASE my_db";
if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  echo "Database my_db created successfully";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error creating database: " . mysqli_error($con);
  }
?>
```

Found here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_create.asp

Comment: w3schools is not the place to learn about much of anything.  It's only decent for when you already know the material and just need a refresher.  The PHP or MySQL manuals would be far better resources.

Comment: well the code is correct and answered the question. Personally I find w3schools a very nice website to learn almost anything

Comment: "Correct" is overstating a tiny bit.  The OO interface is typically recommended instead.

Comment: Well the question was "If there's no way to create a database using PHP and MySQLi" Not what is best recommended. And again "best recommended" in programming is quite vague and depends on variety of reasons why some code is recommended and why some other is not.